# Parent-Child synchronization Using Pause-kill | Both Hang

Tags: c, linux

The parent process creates a Child. Then I want them both to print to STDOUT alternatively.
For this I'm using pause() and kill(pid,SIGUSR1).
I've declared a dummy handler for SIGUSR1.

It compiles fine. Runs fine until it gets stuck. And it gets stuck at different occasions.

I think semaphores will be a way better appraoch to this problem, but I want to use pause-kill to increse my understanding of signals.

I think whats happening is both parent and child get paused because one of them gets descheduled just after the kill() and before pause().
I need to find a way to overcome this.

The expected output is both printing till 4999.

```
void action(int signum){}

int main ()
{
  int i = 0, j = 0; 
  pid_t ret;
  int status;

  signal(SIGUSR1,action);

  ret = fork ();
  if (ret == 0)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
        printf ("Child: %d\n", i);
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
        pause();
      }

      printf ("Child ends\n");
    }
  else
    { 
      for (j = 0; j < 5000; j++){
          printf ("Parent: %d\n", j);
          kill(ret,SIGUSR1);
          pause();
      }
    }
}
```

Some current output I'm getting are-

....
Child: 3844
Parent resumes. Parent: 3844   //after this both hang(or pause I think)

....
Child: 44
Parent resumes. Parent: 44   //after this both hang(or pause I think)

....
Child: 574
Parent resumes. Parent: 574   //after this both hang(or pause I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a window of time between `kill` and `pause` during which a signal can be delivered into the signal handler. In this case `pause` blocks the process forever.

A fix would be to block `SIGUSR1` first and then use [`sigsuspend`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) (§ Notes is instructive) to wait for the `SIGUSR1` in atomic fashion. This way the signal can only be delivered while in the call to `sigsuspend`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void action(int signum) {}

void perror2(char const* msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    pid_t ret;
    sigset_t sigset;

    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    signal(SIGUSR1, action);

    ret = fork();
    if(ret == 0) {
        for(i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
            printf("Child: %d\n", i);
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            if(-1 != sigsuspend(&sigset) || EINTR != errno)
                perror2("sigsuspend");
        }
        printf("Child ends\n");
    }
    else {
        for(j = 0; j < 5000; j++){
            printf("Parent: %d\n", j);
            kill(ret,SIGUSR1);
            if(-1 != sigsuspend(&sigset) || EINTR != errno)
                perror2("sigsuspend");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

An alternative simple fix would be to use pipes for communication between the parent process and its child. Pipes also allow you to pass more than 1 bit of information between the process. E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int const N = 100;

void perror2(char const* msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int child(int from_parent, int to_parent) {
    for(int i = N, j; i--;) {
        if(sizeof j != read(from_parent, &j, sizeof j))
            perror2("child read");
        printf("child received %d\n", j);
        if(sizeof i != write(to_parent, &i, sizeof i))
            perror2("child write");
    }
    return 0;
}

int parent(int from_child, int to_child) {
    for(int i, j  = N; j--;) {
        if(sizeof j != write(to_child, &j, sizeof j))
            perror2("parent write");
        if(sizeof i != read(from_child, &i, sizeof i))
            perror2("parent read");
        printf("parent received %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int to_child[2], to_parent[2];
    if(pipe(to_child))
        perror2("pipe 1");
    if(pipe(to_parent))
        perror2("pipe 2");

    switch(fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror2("fork");
    case 0:
        return child(to_child[0], to_parent[1]);
    default:
        return parent(to_parent[0], to_child[1]);
    }
}
```